# Escaping pipeline in PostgreSQL procedure varchar2

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, enterprisedb

In a PostgreSQL procedure, a variable `QUERY` of type `varchar2` holds a query string that is executed as

`OPEN resultset FOR QUERY;`

In `QUERY` there is a call to the function `string_to_array(mystring,'|')`. How do I escape `'|'` in the query string? I have tried

`QUERY := 'select string_to_array(mystring,''|'') from tablename where mycol=' ||fn_param|| '' ;`

Here `fn_param` is a character varying type input to the procedure. When I call the above procedure from Java it gives the error `ERROR: column "test" does not exist`, where `test` is the value I pass for `fn_param`. The procedure is defined as

```
PROCEDURE myproc(fn_param character varying DEFAULT '0'::character varying, OUT resultset refcursor, OUT err character varying) IS
QUERY   VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
    QUERY := 'select string_to_array(mystring,''|'') from tablename where mycol=' ||fn_param|| ' ';
    OPEN resultset FOR QUERY;
END;
```

Comment: There is no datatype `vsarachar2` in Postgres. And `open resultset for ...` is also invalid PL/pgSQL. What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: EnterpriseDB 9.4.17.26 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu